# Compute joint angles of movement without execution

Tags: joint, ros-melodic, path, cartesian, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning, executing and recording linear robot movement with `computeCartesianPath()`.

I would like to "simulate" this program. Essentially just computing the previously recorded movement (format: joint angles with fixed sampling frequency).

I am not sure how to go about this without actually executing the movement on the real or simulated robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337515/compute-joint-angles-of-movement-without-execution/) by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:
This confuses me:

> I would like to "simulate" this program.

but:

> I am not sure how to go about this without actually executing the movement on the real or **simulated robot**.

What does "simulate" mean in the first sentence?

Are you asking how to concatenate two trajectories?

**Comment by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on 2019-11-13**:
Essentially, I have a bunch of linear movements, say 400, that I want to evaluate, i.e. what joint angles would be commanded. If I compute, execute, record and log the joint angles of every single linear movement, then my program takes very long. Since I am only using IK here, I was wondering if it is possible to just compute the joint angles that would be commanded if I would execute the very same linear movement. That way, I want to save time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:
So you want to `computeCartesianPath(..)` and then process the output without sending it off for execution?

**Comment by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on 2019-11-13**:
Yes, exactly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:\

> I would like to "simulate" this program.

This will be pedantic, but: the output of `computeCartesianPath(..)` is not what I would call a "program". It's a series of joint angles with associated timing information. With a stretch, that could be considered similar to a (traditional) robot program containing only joint motions, but even then it would be far from an actual program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the arguments to `computeCartesianPath(..)` is a reference to a [moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/RobotTrajectory.html) instance (the `trajectory` argument).

That reference is used to store the result of the interpolation. For typical robots (ie: serial manipulators), the `joint_trajectory` field of the `moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory` would be the one you'd be interested in.

As this is just a regular [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) you could do whatever you want with it, including iterating over all the points and inspecting the joint angles.

> Since I am only using IK here, I was wondering if it is possible to just compute the joint angles that would be commanded if I would execute a linear movement.

It's already a trajectory in joint space, so unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't believe you'd need to use IK here at all.

---

Edit:

> > It's already a trajectory in joint space, unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't believe you'd need to use IK here at all.

> I thought `computeCartesianPath()` generates a straight line in the cartesian space and then translates that to joint angles using IK.

Yes, that is what it does, more or less.

But that is what `computeCartesianPath(..)` does. I still don't understand how IK is involved in your side.

> I figured `computeCartesianPath()` may look "in the past" to not command instant configuration changes.

It doesn't really 'command' anything (it just interpolates), but while the function does try to minimise joint space distance between consecutive points, it is dependent on the configured IK solver to provide it with solutions. If those solutions lie very far from each other, `computeCartesianPath(..)` cannot avoid sometimes using a solution that would result in a configuration change.

The `jump_threshold` argument can be used to configure the threshold, but again, if your IK solver returns "bad" solutions, there's only so much `computeCartesianPath(..)` can do.

If you don't need microsecond-range solve times, I'd recommend using [trac_ik](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) with `solve_type` set to `Distance`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-13**:
It would be good to tell us why you want to look at the trajectories. Do you want to check for configuration changes?

**Comment by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on 2019-11-13**:
Thanks for the answer, Ill try it that way and then report back!

I want to check for paths that command configurations in close proximity to singularities via evaluating joint velocities.

> It's already a trajectory in joint space, unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't believe you'd need to use IK here at all.

I thought `computeCartesianPath()` generates a straight line in the cartesian space and then translates that to joint angles using IK. I figured `computeCartesianPath()` may look "in the past" to not command instant configuration changes.